# How to fix Disk Read error when trying to read sector

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, osdev, bios

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Eexr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf) on building a simple operating system. My problem is it calls a disk load function, and when I boot it up, it gives me a Disk read error. Here is my boot_sect.asm code:

```
[org 0x7c00]
KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x1000

    mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl

    mov bp, 0x9000
    mov sp, bp


    mov bx, MSG_REAL_MODE
    call print_string

    call load_kernel
    mov bx, MSG_LOAD_KERNEL
    call print_string
    call switch_to_pm

    jmp $

%include "print_string.asm"
%include "disk_load.asm"
%include "gdt.asm"
%include "print_string_pm.asm"
%include "switch_to_pm.asm"

[bits 16]

load_kernel:

    mov bx, MSG_LOAD_KERNEL
    call print_string

    mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET
    mov dh, 15
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]

    call disk_load 

    ret

[bits 32]
BEGIN_PM:

    mov ebx, MSG_PROT_MODE
    call print_string_pm

    call KERNEL_OFFSET

    jmp $


BOOT_DRIVE db 0
MSG_REAL_MODE db "Started in 16-bit Real Mode", 0
MSG_PROT_MODE db "Successfully landed in 32-bit Protected Mode", 0
MSG_LOAD_KERNEL db "Loading kernel into memory", 0

; Padding
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

and my disk_load.asm:

```
; load DH sectors to ES:BX from drive DL
disk_load :

    push dx ; Store DX on stack so later we can recall
    ; how many sectors were request to be read ,
    ; even if it is altered in the meantime

    mov ah, 0x02 ; BIOS read sector function
    mov al, dh ; Read DH sectors
    mov ch, 0x00 ; Select cylinder 0
    mov dh, 0x00 ; Select head 0
    mov cl, 0x02 ; Start reading from second sector ( i.e.
    ; after the boot sector )

    int 0x13; BIOS interrupt
    jc disk_error ; Jump if error ( i.e. carry flag set )
    pop dx ; Restore DX from the stack
    cmp dh, al ; if AL ( sectors read ) != DH ( sectors expected )
    jne disk_error2 ; display error message
    ret

disk_error :
    mov bx , DISK_ERROR_MSG
    call print_string
    jmp $
disk_error2 :
    mov bx , DISK_ERROR_MSG2
    call print_string
    jmp $

; Variables
DISK_ERROR_MSG db " Disk read error 1 !" , 0
DISK_ERROR_MSG2 db " Disk read error 2 !" , 0
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58370647/how-to-fix-disk-read-error-in-my-bootloader#:%7E:text=Are%20you%20sure%20that%20the%20ES%20register%20contains%20the%20correct%20value%3F) says that I might need `es` to be zero, but when I put

```
xor bx, bx
mov es, bx
```

above the `int 0x13`, It just hangs at the interrupt. How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

In this example I made it display `hello` after the interrupt, however, it does not display it unless I delete `xor bx, bx mov es, bx`, so that is why I thought it got stuck there:

```
; load DH sectors to ES:BX from drive DL
disk_load :

    push dx ; Store DX on stack so later we can recall
    ; how many sectors were request to be read ,
    ; even if it is altered in the meantime

    mov ah, 0x02 ; BIOS read sector function
    mov al, dh ; Read DH sectors
    mov ch, 0x00 ; Select cylinder 0
    mov dh, 0x00 ; Select head 0
    mov cl, 0x02 ; Start reading from second sector ( i.e.
    ; after the boot sector )

    xor bx, bx
    mov es, bx

    int 0x13; BIOS interrupt

    mov bx, message         ;  This should print `hello` after the interrrupt
    call print_string       ;

    jc disk_error ; Jump if error ( i.e. carry flag set )
    pop dx ; Restore DX from the stack
    cmp dh, al ; if AL ( sectors read ) != DH ( sectors expected )
    jne disk_error2 ; display error message
    ret

    . . .
```

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I am pretty sure `ah` is `0xc`. I ran like this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 os-image -s & gdb

target remote localhost:1234

info register ah
```

and the output is

`ah             0xc                 12`

Also, my commands to compile are:

```
i386-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o

ld -m elf_i386 -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 kernel.o --oformat binary

nasm boot_sect.asm -f bin -o boot_sect.bin

cat boot_sect.bin kernel.bin > os-image

qemu-system-x86_64 os-image
```

Comment: It can't hang there, you probably misunderstood something. Also you forgot to initialize `ds`.

Comment: When you single-step it in Bochs' built-in debugger, or in something attached to QEMU as a GDB-remote, what instruction exactly does it hang on?

Comment: You change `bx` just before `int 13h`. Buffer is  `es:bx 0000:0000`. This destroys `ivt` entries. Probably disk int too. Set `es` to 0 before call to `disk_load`. Maybe it'll work .

Answer (score 2):

> when I boot it up, it gives me a Disk read error.

It would be most useful to show us the actual *status byte* that BIOS returns in the AH register whenever the carry flag is set on return!

---

Please read [Disk Read Error while loading sectors into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216893/disk-read-error-while-loading-sectors-into-memory/34382681#34382681) for explanations and a working code.

> ```
> [org 0x7c00]
> KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x1000
>
>     mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl
>
>     mov bp, 0x9000
>     mov sp, bp
> ```

When BIOS places your bootloader program in memory, the only register that you can be sure of is DL which holds the *driveID*. Since the segment registers are very important in real mode programming, you have to set  these up correctly. In accordance with your `[org 0x7c00]`, next is what you mandatory need to write:

```
[org 0x7C00]
KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x1000

  xor  ax, ax
  mov  ds, ax
  mov  es, ax
  mov  ss, ax            ; Keep these two together and
  mov  sp, 0x9000        ;  very importantly in this order
  mov  [BOOT_DRIVE], dl
```

I suggest that you swap your current *disk_load* procedure for the one in the answer for which I provided a link. Make sure to call it appropriately.

---

> ```
> int 0x13; BIOS interrupt
>
> mov bx, message         ;  This should print `hello` after the interrrupt
> call print_string       ;
>
> jc disk_error ; Jump if error ( i.e. carry flag set )
> ```

It is a good debugging technique to display temporary messages to the screen, but don't forget that the *print_string* procedure will have destroyed that carry flag obtained from the BIOS.ReadSectors function 02h.
For a successful inspection of the carry flag use `pushf` and `popf` as in:

```
  mov  ah, 02h     ; BIOS.ReadSectors
  int  0x13
  pushf
  mov  bx, message
  call print_string
  popf
  jc   disk_error  ; Jump if error ( i.e. carry flag set )
```

This will preserve the carry flag on the stack. And if you can't be sure that *print_string* already preserves AX, then preserve AX here in the same fashion...